# Enabling Speech in existing Dispatch model of luis and qna

Tags: botframework, speech, azure-cognitive-services

I have my web app bot working over dispatch model. I want my bot to take input using speech also within the same web channel. So how can i implement this within my existing architecture?

Comment: To clarify, you are wanting to enable speech-to-text? And, this is for Web Chat (Web Chat Channel or [BotFramework-WebChat](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat)?

Comment: @StevenKanberg yes you are right

Comment: Both the Web Chat Channel (found in the bot's settings in Azure) is different from BotFramework-WebChat. Can you tell me which it is you are trying to use?

Comment: I am right now using BotFramework-WebChat channel from Azure. I want to integrate speech to text in my web client only

Answer (score 0):

Look over the BotFramework-Webchat [06.c.cognitive-services-speech-services-js](https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat/tree/master/samples/06.c.cognitive-services-speech-services-js). It demonstrates how to setup Web Chat to accept user voice input. This input is sent as a activity to the bot which you can parse using dispatch for matching against LUIS and QnA, as normal.

Hope of help!